# How can I find which instruction is crashing my program with an Illegal Instruction error?

Tags: gcc, inline-assembly, mingw32

I am using Mingw32 on windows and trying to read the CPU microcode revision.

I am getting a crash with illegal instruction (seen via gdb) but I have been unable to determine which instruction is causing it.

How can I find out which instruction is illegal, and for bonus points what is wrong with my program?  I am trying to print the EDX register.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int cookie = 42;

    asm(
        "MOVL $0x08, %%ecx\n\t"
        "XOR %%eax, %%eax\n\t"
        "XOR %%edx, %%edx\n\t"
        "WRMSR\n\t"
        "MOVL 1, %%EAX\n\t"
        "cpuid\n\t"
        "MOVL $0x08, %%ecx\n\t"
        "rdmsr\n\t"
        : "=rd"(cookie)
        :
        : "eax", "ecx", "edx"
    );

    printf("%d\n", cookie);
}
```

Comment: Your problem is almost certainly `WRMSR`, since (according to the docs): *This instruction must be executed at privilege level 0 or in real-address mode*.  However if you comment out the write, `RDMSR` will give you the same problem (for the same reason).  To answer the actual question: You would normally find this by stepping thru the code with a debugger.

Comment: Additionally, I believe `CPUID` changes the value of ebx, but you don't list that as being modified.  This could lead to other crashes in subsequent code.

Comment: Your debugger should stop on the instruction that faults.  Use `disas` or `layout reg` to see which one.   And BTW, `"=rd"` means the compiler has a choice of any register or RDX.  You need `"=d"` for that constraint, and an `"ebx"` clobber instead of `"edx"`.  (An output can't be a clobber.)

Answer (score 0):

libcpuid compiles on MinGW-w64 (http://libcpuid.sourceforge.net/).

Maybe you can use that to get the information you need or take a peek in its code on how access should be done?

Comment: CPUID is easy, there's no need for WRMSR or RDMSR if you just want CPUID info.  https://www.sandpile.org/x86/msr.htm doesn't mention the MSR 0x08 that this code is trying to write for some reason.